# Proving $f(z) = \frac{Re(z)}{|z|}$ has a limit in $|z| = 0$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits

I need to prove that:

$$f(z) = \frac{Re(z)}{|z|}$$

and

$$g(z) = \frac{Im(z^2)}{|z^2|}$$

both have limit at $z=0$

If I see $z$ as $z = x+iy$ I have:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

but if I take this limit at $y = x$ we have:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^2}}$$

won't that depend on the signal of $x$? So wouldn't this limit be inexistent?

For $g$ we should have:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2xy}{\sqrt{(x^2-y^2)^2+(2xy)^2}} = \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2xy}{\sqrt{x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4+4x^2y^2}} = $$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}$$

doesn't this go to infinity as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither limit exists. For the first one, if we approach the origin along the line $y=0$ then the result is 
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{|x|} $$
which does not exist. For the second one, if we approach the origin along the line $y=0$ the limit is zero, while if we approach the origin along the line $y=x$ the limit is
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x^2}{x^2+x^2}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Well you're right. These functions do not have a limit as $z\rightarrow 0$. It's not even true if $z$ is a real number as
$\dfrac{x}{|x|}$
has no limit as $x\rightarrow 0$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$.